# Unable to debug Lambda Expression IntelliJ Ultimate 2018.1

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, lambda, java-8

I am running Junit test case in Debug mode, it works fine with normal method calls. When I try to debug a lambda expression, control doesn't go inside.

I tried installing Java Stream Debugger but support has not yet extended for IntelliJ Ultimate 2018.1 IDE

```
public TestLambda lambdaExpression() {
        int width=10;
        TestLambda d2;
        //with lambda
        return d2=()->{
            System.out.println("Drawing "+width);
            System.out.println("Drawing1 "+width);
            System.out.println("Drawing2 "+width);
        };
    }
```

I want debugger point to go to each sysout statement. I am able to debug the same expression using Eclipse.

Comment: The control will only go into the lambda body, when the method declared in the `TestLambda` interface is actually invoked. In the code you’ve shown, this does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment I updated the code and it worked fine. My actual issue was related to Bean initialization via spring hence no execution was written in Config file. Hence the debugger was not going inside.

Updated Code:

```
public void lambdaExpression() {
        int width=10;
        //with lambda
        TestLambda d2=()->{
            System.out.println("Drawing "+width);
            System.out.println("Drawing "+width);
            System.out.println("Drawing "+width);
        };

        d2.draw();
    }
```